# Beginner stuck on Ruby on Rails project "...must exist"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So my assignment asks me to generate a page that handles students, courses, and sections. I'm supposed to be using many_to_many or some similar method to be able to list all this shared data. My specific problem is that I created a new table (rails g scaffold enrollment students:references sections:references) that doesn't seem to work. when I attempt to create a new enrollment using a student and section, I get an error stating that "Section must exist" [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CX6l.png) . I have no idea where this error is coming from. The sections field in this view is only populated with existing sections, so the fact that it says "must exist" is very...confusing. Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this? I've rebuilt this project 3 times trying different methods and am just... stuck. I'll post the relevant code, but if I'm wrong about which sections you may need to see, I'll happily post the rest.

```
class Enrollment < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :section
belongs_to :student 
end

<%= form_with(model: enrollment, local: true) do |form| %>
<% if enrollment.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(enrollment.errors.count, "error") %> 
prohibited this enrollment from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% enrollment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= form.label :student_id %>
<%= form.collection_select :student_id, Student.order(:student_name), :id, 
:student_id, include_blank:true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= form.label :course_id %>
<%= form.collection_select :course_id, Course.order(:name), :id, :name, 
include_blank: true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= form.label :sections_number %>
<%= form.collection_select :section_number, Section.all, :id, 
:section_number, include_blank:false %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
<%= form.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>

class Section < ApplicationRecord
has_many :enrollments
has_and_belongs_to_many :students, through: :enrollments       
belongs_to :course

def numsem
    "#{course.name} #{course_id}"
end
end
```

L

-----------------------EDIT TO ADD CONTROLLER CODE----------------

```
class EnrollmentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_enrollment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /enrollments
# GET /enrollments.json
def index
@enrollments = Enrollments.all
end

# GET /enrollments/1
# GET /enrollments/1.json
def show
end

# GET /enrollments/new
def new
@enrollment = Enrollments.new
@sections = Section.all
@students = Student.all
end

# GET /enrollments/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /enrollments
# POST /enrollments.json
def create
@enrollment = Enrollments.new(enrollment_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @enrollment.save
    format.html { redirect_to @enrollment, notice: 'Enrollments was 
successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @enrollment }
   else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @enrollment.errors, status: 
 :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
 end

# PATCH/PUT /enrollments/1
# PATCH/PUT /enrollments/1.json
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @enrollment.update(enrollment_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @enrollment, notice: 'Enrollments was 
 successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @enrollment }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @enrollment.errors, status:      
:unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# DELETE /enrollments/1
# DELETE /enrollments/1.json
def destroy
@enrollment.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to enrollments_index_url, notice: 'Enrollments was 
successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_enrollment
  @enrollment = Enrollments.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list 
through.
def enrollment_params
  params.require(:enrollment).permit(:student_id, :section_id)
end
end
```

Comment: What does your controller method look like? What's in `params` in the controller method when the error occurs?

Comment: Hey Mu, thanks for responding. I'm posting the controller now.

Comment: oh, and I can screenshot it, but i'm using a collection in the form so that my only options for the parameters are valid items from both student and sections, and those are showing up in their individual views just fine, so i know (i'm fairly sure) they aren't the problem

Comment: One thing: The `has_and_belongs_to_many` should be changed to `has_many`. Has many through and HABTM are similar in that they’re both used for many to many associations, but the difference is what your join table is. HABTM gives you no control over the join table, while has many though is used when the join table is also a model that you can access, meaning it has useful attributes on it. HABTM is discouraged because in a lot of cases, you’ll eventually find that you want the join table to have some attributes more than just ids.

Comment: Also, you seem to be using Rails 5, not 3 like your tag shows. By default all belongs_to associations have presence validation on them. So when you create your enrollment, you must not be providing a student.

Comment: thats the thing, I am adding a student and a section, the section is the problem, it keeps stating that it needs to exist. if i list it as optional under the model for enrollments then it will create an enrollment entry, with the student info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Section must exist

The error is because you are trying to save the `@enrollment` with a **nil** `section_id` which raises that exception. The problem lies with your **form** where you have this

```
<%= form.collection_select :section_number, Section.all, :id, 
:section_number, include_blank:false %>
```

which should be

```
<%= form.collection_select :section_id, Section.all, :id, 
:section_number, include_blank:false %>
```